# Force execution of main queue in progressHandler (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiimage, phasset

I am downloading an image from the cloud using requestImageDataForAsset. I am attaching a PHImageRequestOptions with progress handler to get notified of download progress regularly. In the progress handler I am drawing a progress UIImage and refresh a UIButton with this image.

However the progress handler is loaded in background queue and I need to refresh the UIButton image on the main thread.

My issue is that the main thread gets executed only after the full download has finished.

Is there a way to force main thread execution at a given moment ?

```
        PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
        options.progressHandler = ^(double progress, NSError * _Nullable error, BOOL * _Nonnull stop, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            NSLog(@"Progress: %f %%",progress*100.f);
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
            CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            <create UIImage>
            progressImg=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"Updating button image");
                [self->testButton setImage:progressImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [self->testButton setNeedsDisplay];
            });
        };

        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:options resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info)
        {
             <actions>
        }];
```

Receiving output:

```
2018-06-12 10:30:34.765372+0300 App[12894:2931379] Progress: 0.000000 %
2018-06-12 10:30:34.828532+0300 App[12894:2931379] Progress: 0.000000 %
2018-06-12 10:30:35.724429+0300 App[12894:2931379] Progress: 0.000000 %
2018-06-12 10:30:41.703484+0300 App[12894:2931379] Progress: 0.042285 %
2018-06-12 10:30:44.241504+0300 App[12894:2931379] Progress: 5.973034 %
2018-06-12 10:30:44.581450+0300 App[12894:2931410] Progress: 62.652379 %
2018-06-12 10:30:44.753667+0300 App[12894:2931379] Progress: 99.009919 %
2018-06-12 10:30:44.756178+0300 App[12894:2931379] Progress: 100.000000 %
2018-06-12 10:30:44.859165+0300 App[12894:2931410] Progress: 100.000000 %
2018-06-12 10:30:44.884380+0300 App[12894:2931279] Updating button image
2018-06-12 10:30:44.884484+0300 App[12894:2931279] Updating button image
2018-06-12 10:30:44.884550+0300 App[12894:2931279] Updating button image
2018-06-12 10:30:44.884600+0300 App[12894:2931279] Updating button image
2018-06-12 10:30:44.884646+0300 App[12894:2931279] Updating button image
2018-06-12 10:30:44.884693+0300 App[12894:2931279] Updating button image
2018-06-12 10:30:44.884745+0300 App[12894:2931279] Updating button image
2018-06-12 10:30:44.884797+0300 App[12894:2931279] Updating button image
2018-06-12 10:30:44.884843+0300 App[12894:2931279] Updating button image
```

Comment: Did you try to put UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions code in main queue block?

Comment: I tried to put the whole progressHandler in the main queue, but the same happens, the main thread gets executed once full image downloaded.

Comment: See this , that might be helpful http://nshipster.com/phimagemanager/

Comment: Thanks, saw this. Unfortunately I still face the issue that all my main thread activities are launched after download is completed ; which doesn't seem to be the case in their example.

Answer (score 0):

Issue came from the options where I needed to set `options.synchronous = NO`